# Hide cursor for only one Adobe AIR window

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have the following code which hides the cursor for an Adobe AIR app (**JavaScript**):

```
window.runtime.flash.ui.Mouse.hide();
```

However I have two screens displayed when the app is run, and I only want the cursor hidden on **one of the windows**... How can I do this? As the above code will hide it for all windows!

What I have tried (based on the code posted below by Andrey):

```
window.nativeWindow.addEventListener(air.MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function(){

    window.runtime.flash.ui.Mouse.hide();

});

window.nativeWindow.addEventListener(air.MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, function(){

    window.runtime.flash.ui.Mouse.show();

});
```

This code lives inside the ACTUAL HTML that is loaded into the window, so it only runs on the window it exists on... but doesn't work...

Also tried: MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT

I've also tried to add the mouse hide on the actual window:

```
var secondWindow = air.HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(false, options, false, largestScreen.bounds);

    secondWindow.window.runtime.flash.ui.Mouse.hide();
```

Which also doesn't work... Any ideas on how I can achieve this on just one window?

Answer (score 0):

Hide mouse on roll over event and show on roll out:

```
private var window:Window;

private function init():void
{
    window = new Window();
    window.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, window_onRollOver);
    window.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, window_onRollOut);
    window.open();
}

private function window_onRollOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Mouse.hide();
}

private function window_onRollOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Mouse.show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's JavaScript-based. See my updated question.